# How do I catch SQLITE exceptions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a try/catch sequence in my code, and it is not catching errors at all. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Some background. A user presses a button and we update a row in an SQLITE table. That column being updated is UNIQUE (i.e. it should not allow for duplicates. I want to catch the error for when a duplicate entry is attempted:

Here's the code:

```
                IconButton( icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle,color: Colors.redAccent, size: 40),
                    onPressed: ()
                    {

                      setState(() async
                      {

                        print(textController.text);
                        try
                        {
                          await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO MyRoutines(MyRoutineName) VALUES (?)', [textController.text]);


                        }
                        catch(e)
                        {
                          switch(e)
                          {
                            case 19:
                              print('This is a duplicate');
                              break;

                          }
                        }

                      });


                    },
                  ),
```

So as you can see, from the Run errors or output, I see that code=19 is given when a duplicate entry occurs. I try and catch this, yet nothing happens.. i.e. that print statement is never triggered.

What am I doing wrong? I need to catch ALL SQL errors, and I have no idea how to catch the errors or what the error codes are.

I checked on the net, yet I could not find it. Can anyone provide some light on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps your switch statement.

Having caught the error 'e'  maybe you have to switch on something like e.errNo.

Comment: yes. that's exactly what I need, but e.errNo doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you write the 'e' object to the console so that we can look at its structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your function within a try catch block and add a tag on SqliteException. You should be able to capture the error there. For example

```
try {
 // sql query
} on SqliteException catch(e) {
 // access the message {e.explanation}
}
```